# "As following" vs "as follows"

Tags: word-choice, difference, phrase-usage, as

Which of the following sentences is more appropriate?

> 1. The reasons for these decisions are as following:
> 2. The reasons for these decisions are as follows:

> 1. This operator is defined as following:
> 2. This operator is defined as follows:

Comment: "As follows" and "the following" are common collocations, but "as following" is not and sounds ungrammatical.

Comment: @snailplane, Instead of <as following>, What about <as the following>?

Comment: @Pacerier https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68376/as-follows-vs-as-the-following says no.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

"As follows" would be the more appropriate usage.

An alternative would be "The reasons for these decisions are:" or "The operator is defined by:".

Comment: Would *"as the followings"* be an appropriate alternative?

Comment: @xpt: No "As the followings" is even more wrong because "following" is an adjective used as a noun, not a noun in its own right. Just like we talk about groups of people using nominalized adjectives: "the rich", "the poor", "the sick", "the young", "the elderly"; but never "the riches", "the poors", "the sicks", or "the youngs", "the elderlies".

Answer (score 24):

In case anyone like myself a few minutes ago wonders why we use "*as follows*" and not "*as follow*", here is an interesting [explanation](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/02/as-follows.html):

> The construction is always singular: “My position is as follows” …
>   “The three points are as follows” …  “Her favorite books were as
>   follows,” and so on.
>
> The Oxford English Dictionary describes the phrase “as follows” as “a
>   prefatory formula used to introduce a statement, enumeration, or the
>   like.”
>
> In this formula, the OED says, the verb is impersonal and should
>   always be used in the singular—“follows.” Use of the plural verb
>   “follow,” Oxford adds, is “incorrect.”
>
> Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage concurs, saying “All
>   experts agree” that “as follows regularly has the singular form of the
>   verb—follows—even if preceded by a plural.”
>
> The OED’s earliest examples of the phrase in writing are in the
>   singular: “als her fast folowys” (as here directly follows), from
>   1426, and “He openly sayde as foloweth” (He openly said as follows),
>   from 1548.
>
> A more telling example, from George Campbell’s The Philosophy of
>   Rhetoric (1776), discusses the correct use of the phrase:
>
> “Analogy as well as usage favour this mode of expression. ‘The
>   conditions of the agreement were as follows’; and not as follow. A few
>   late writers have inconsiderately adopted this last form through a
>   mistake of the construction.”
>
> An inquiring mind might well ask why this is true. Here’s an answer
>   from Fowler’s Modern English Usage (rev. 3rd ed.), edited by R. W.
>   Burchfield:
>
> “The phrase as follows is naturally always used cataphorically, i.e.
>   with forward reference, and is not replaced by as follow even when the
>   subject of the sentence is plural: His preferences are as follows … ;
>   his view is as follows.”
>
> “The reason for its fixed form,” the usage guide adds, “is that it was
>   originally an impersonal construction = ‘as it follows.’ ”
>
> In case you’re still not convinced, Garner’s Modern American Usage
>   (3rd ed.) has this to say:
>
> “As follows is always the correct form, even for an enumeration of
>   many things. The expression is elliptical for as it follows—not as
>   they follow.”

Also, the [Columbia Guide to Standard American English](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0231069898) says:

> Whether the preceding matter is plural or not, *as follows* is always
>   singular: The reasons for these decisions are as follows. To use *as*
>   *follow* instead is sufficiently precious sounding to make your reader
>   break stride: don’t do it. You can use *the following* instead (e.g. "You must do the following: blah blah blah"), but you
>   needn’t. Less stiff would be *The reasons for these decisions are*
>   *these*, or *Here are my reasons*, or *My reasons are, first,…,* and the
>   like.

Answer (score 10):

You want to use the form

> The reasons for these decisions are as follows:
>
> This operator is defined as follows:

The other two sentences are incorrect.