# "As follows" vs "as follow"

Tags: plural-forms, singular

When we want to write something (often lists or points), we say:

> the main points are **as follows**:
>
> 1. Abc
> 2. Def
> 3. Ghi

"Points" is plural but we still write "follows". Why is it not "**as follow**" as in:

> the main points are **as follow**:

So why is it "follows"? Are both correct?

Comment: Read [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31673/106592) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'As follows' means 'as described in the passage that follows this'.

> What comes next, usually in the form of a list. For example, Mary planned her day as follows: returning all phone calls; a department meeting; lunch with her colleagues; library research. This term is always put in the singular (“follows”) even though it applies to numerous items and is frequently followed by a colon. It was first recorded in 1548.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/as-follows

The original example is correct.

The other version is not natural.

Comment: I suppose it means "as described in the passage that follows this".